# AppSync - VTL support for hash MD5 from a string array

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl

In the AppSync mapping request template, I need to generate ***MD5 hash*** from String array to get the same value which is generated in some other place using node.js library '***object-hash***' (cannot change that).

[Utility Helpers in $util](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html) offers only `$util.base64Encode( byte[] ) : String`

Am I missing something or there is definitely no hash MD5 support for now in AppSync VTL?

Comment: You are correct; at this time generating md5 hashes is not supported in AppSync VTL.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron_H. Hope it will be supported soon.

Comment: I haven't tested this but I believe you have access to all the String functions within VTL. Perhaps the hashCode method could be of use. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_hashcode.htm